# Git merge random commit on another branch after a merge

Tags: git, git-branch, git-merge

Ok... so I merged these two branches together that my co-worker and I were working on. However, he decides to stay on his old branch and do another commit/push.... So now I have to find a way to merge that commit that is hanging out there in the middle of nowhere onto the master branch.

Here is a picture showing the dilemna:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/b8baP.png

I read into cherry picking, but I'm not sure if I want to go that route. I'm frustrating since he didn't go back onto the master before doing the commit/push... but this commit will conflict with a lot of my files on the master branch so I need to be able to merge and resolve them.. Is there a way to go about doing this with Git?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you explain why cherry picking won't work for your scenario?

Comment: I heard there are consequences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply merge the other branch (flyerbuilder) again. Git is clever enough to figure out that it does not need to merge all commits again – it will only pick the new ones for the merge.

Comment: He doesn't have the merged one before he made that commit, but I can resolve all of them again.
Edit - OHHHH very nice! Ok I will do that =)